# How to define a large number of assumptions?

Tags: assumptions

Please consider the following *simple* and *larger* example:

```
varSimple = ToExpression@CharacterRange["a", "b"];
fSimple = Total@Map[Sqrt[#^2] &, varSimple];
assumpSimple = And[Element[varSimple, Integers] , a >= 0 , b >= 0];
simpfSimple = Simplify[fSimple, assumpSimple]
(*a+b*)
```

When one defines a larger function such as `fLarge`, it is very inconvenient to type `character1>=0 && ... && character#>=0` for the whole `CharacterRange` to define the assumptions.

```
varLarge = ToExpression@CharacterRange["a", "z"];
fLarge = Total@Map[Sqrt[#^2] &, varLarge];
assumpLarge = And[Element[varLarge, Integers] , a >= 0 , ... , z=>0];
simpfSimple = Simplify[fSimple, assumpLarge]
(*a+...+z*)
```

**Question 1**

Since `And` (as well as `Alternatives`) cannot cope with `List` as an argument, how can I combine a larger number of expressions with `And` (or `Alternatives`)?

**Question 2**

With `ToExpression@CharacterRange["a", "z"]` the number of variables is limited to 24. Is there another (easy) way to define a larger number of variables?

Comment: Why should your variables be one character long?

Comment: like `var=ToExpression@ (# <> "1") & /@ CharacterRange["a", "z"]` would produce another 26 ;-) and then `And @@ Map[# > 0 &, var]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For question 1:**
To `And` together a list you can use `Apply` (it is usually written as `@@`, see the docs for [more information](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html)):

```
And@@Thread[{a, b, c} >= 0]
(* a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 *)
```

For `Alternatives` you can:

```
Alternatives@@{a, b, c}
(* a | b | c *)
```

**For question 2:**
You can call your variables `x[i]`

```
And@@Thread[(x[#] & /@ Range[50]) >= 0]
(* x[1] >= 0 && ... && x[50] >= 0  *)
```

Full example:

```
varLarge = x[#] & /@ Range[50];
fLarge = Total@Map[Sqrt[#^2] &, varLarge];
assumpLarge = And[Element[varLarge, Integers], And @@ Thread@(varLarge >= 0)];
simpfSimple = Simplify[fLarge, assumpLarge]
(* x[1] + ... + x[50] *)
```

When calling variables `x[i]` you can also use `x[_] >= 0` as your assumption, but for some reason that runs *really* slow for me.

If you have the same assumptions for everything involved you can put something like `_ \[Element] Integers && _ >= 0` as your assumption since `_` is a pattern that matches everything.